# The Smart Contract Works but it does not inject into web 3, the transaction stays as pending

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-deployment, etherscan, smart-contract-wallets

I have written a smart contract that works correctly when deploying, and even in my metamask I see that it has been created correctly. Later when I try to find my contract in Etherscan I see that it is pending, and I think it is due to an error that I cannot locate in the code; but in Solidity there doesn't seem to be any errors.
This is the code:

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    // OpenZeppelin Contracts v4.4.1 (finance/PaymentSplitter.sol)
    
    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
    
    import '@openzeppelin/contracts/finance/PaymentSplitter.sol';
    
    contract PAYMENTS2 is PaymentSplitter {
    
        constructor(address[] memory _payees, uint256[] memory _shares) PaymentSplitter(_payees, _shares) payable{}
        
    
    }
```

Info:
[image: This is what I get in the terminal]
[image: Metamask (confirmed transaction)]

The GAS LIMIT is on 3000000.

The status in thr Etherscan is: This transaction has been included and will be reflected in a short while.

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Hi Never3stress! Did the contract appear? If the network is busy and the transaction fee is low the transaction might take longer to mine. Are you deploying to testnet? Etherscan is a closed source third party block explorer so sometimes test networks aren't updated as quickly as mainnet.

Comment: Hello Ismael! Yes, I´m deploying to the testnet, I know it takes a while but I wanted for 4 hours and nothing changed, even the fee was set back into the account as nothing happened.

Comment: The contract is quite simple I don't think the problem is the contract. If you have the transaction hash you could check in a block explorer the status. If it takes longer than 10 minutes in a testnet either the gas fee is too low, there is a pending transaction with low gas fee, the wallet is broken.